# Logic issue in if statmentents returning nulls string

Tags: java, logic

I'm learning Java and I'm making a simple program that checks whether the variables x y and z are equal, different, or neither equal or different.

Currently, when I have the values for x y and z as 1 1 2 I get a null string. I don't have a print line statement that prints a null string. I just can't wrap my head around what I'm missing.

```
public static void printEqual(int x, int y, int z){
    if (x>0 && y>0 && z>0){
        if (x == y && x == z){
            System.out.println("All numbers are equal");
        }

        if (x != y && x != z && z != y){
            System.out.println("All numbers are different");
        }

        if (!(x==y || x==z || z==y)){
            System.out.println("Neither all are equal or different");
        }
    }

    else  {
        System.out.println("Invalid Value");
    }
}
```

Comment: `!(x==y || x==z || z==y)` is identical to `x != y && x != z && z != y` by [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already checked if values were all identicals, or all different. One only option remains : Neither of thoses two cases ! So you can just write an else.

By the way,

```
!(x==y || x==z || z==y)
```

Is equivalent to

```
x != y && x != z && z != y
```

Edit : If you really want to write this condition, it's simply !(AllEquals || AllDifferent)